# Resque Mailer fails to send email due to wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I'm a Rails newbie, so please forgive any ignorance on my part. The issue I'm having is that I have a Resque job setup to send an email. I have the job running, but it produces an error:

```
Unable to deliver email [send_daily_digest_email]: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)
```

I get this same error when I try to test the mailer from console...

```
TicketMailer.send_daily_digest_email("emailaddress@domain.com").deliver_now
```

Here is the mailer code:

```
class TicketMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  layout 'mailer'
  include Resque::Mailer
  default :from => 'test <test@ignore.com>'

  def send_daily_digest_email(email)
    mail(:to => email, :subject => 'test')
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong? Where should I look to figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: try with `TicketMailer.send_daily_digest_email("emailaddress@domain.com").deliver`

Comment: This just returns true in the console and fails with the same previous error in the queue.

Comment: I see, I think you're using Rails 5, right ?, if so, take a look here https://github.com/zapnap/resque_mailer/issues/90

Comment: You are 100% right -- thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the issue was due to Rails 5 not being fully supported in the current release of the resque-mailer gem. Support is built in now, but I had to pull from master on the repo:

```
gem "resque_mailer", :git => "https://github.com/zapnap/resque_mailer.git"
```